# I am not able to call my function getdata() which is a function in model "Student_info" from my controller "StudentController"

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I have already done many things from `$ composer dump-autoload` and changing the path \App\Student_info::getdata() but nothing seems to solve this problem.

Here is error I am getting [(fullsize)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EH43k.png):

[image]

Comment: Did you already check that you don't have a typo in the class name? Also, check if you set the correct namespace in app/Student_info.php and imported it properly in StudentController (use App\Student_info;)

Comment: Try to read more documentation and get to know standards (naming conventions), how to call models etcetera. Its all there in documentation, try free laracasts also! Free education for all.